# Ember Data saving

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having a ton of trouble with updating a model in my Ember application.  I can't seem to find good documentation that describes how to update my app.  The following code is what I'm trying.  This sends an update to /playlists/:playlist_id, unfortunately it doesn't send the updated songs as well... is there some callback for pushObject that I can't find?  Am I trying trying to save the wrong thing?

```
App.PlaylistIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    addSong: function(song) {
      songs = this.get('songs');
      songs.pushObject(song);

      this.get('model').save();
    } 
  }
});

App.Playlist = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    songs: DS.hasMany('song'),
});

App.Song = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  artist: DS.attr('string'),
  playlist: DS.belongsTo('playlist'),
});
```

Comment: Is it really true that Songs belong to Playlists? If so, you could simply set the playlist on the song and save the song. The song will include the playlist ID in its PUT.

Comment: in my scenario, I want to save the entire array because I want to persist the order that they are in.  Otherwise, yes, that would be a totally viable option

Comment: Could a song be in more than one Playlist? Because with this model definition A song can only be in one playList

Comment: It can.  I was having issues with the many-to-many, so it may be something I'll need to revisit.